# ios8.3: css color assignment not working

Tags: css, ios8.3

Since I updated to iOS 8.3 I have a strange bug regarding the color assignment in an html element. Opening the pen below in Chrome results in 2 blue checkmarks (which is what I want), in Safari on iOS 8.3 the left one is black and I can't get it to show up in blue:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwMQJr

```
<span class="deliver_status"></span>

.deliver_status {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: hsl(198, 81%, 54%);
    text-shadow: 4px 0px 0px hsl(198, 81%, 54%);
}

.deliver_status::after {
    content: '✔';
}
```

Is this a new bug or am I missing some other needed assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same issue on my site.  It appears to be a new bug with 8.3 with certain unicode characters.  For example, my green ✔ is now black, but my red ✘ is still red.

In addition, the font-size is ignored for the ✔ which you can test on the CodePen site.

Perhaps it is related to the emoticon changes in 8.3 and should be reported to Apple as a bug with Safari.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: The question is "Is this a new bug or am I missing some other needed assignment?" and my answer is that this is a new bug.  How is that not answering the question?

Comment: I submitted bug #20598688 to Apple and included the following link which demonstrates the bug (a slightly simplified version of the one Riesling posted):  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dobvVO

Comment: I was able to work around this bug by using the thinner checkmark ✓ (&#x2713; or &#10003;) and then applying a bold font-weight.